# Gnome: Running custom shell scripts on key press

Tags: ubuntu

I have created a shell script for a custom action which is working fine. I want to run this .sh file (`mon.sh`) on pressing `Alt+F15`.

I have done the following:
In gconf-editor, under `apps>metacity>keybinding_commands`, edited `command_1` with value

> `"/home/administrator/My Scripts/mon.sh"`  (tried without quotes also)

under `apps>metacity>global_keybindings`, edited `run_command_1` with value

> `<Alt>F15`

But the script is not getting executed when pressing Alt+F15

What is that I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure the script is able to run properly as a command? Things to check:  1) the interpreter is specified in the first line of the script as #!/path/to/interpreter.  2) the file has the execute bit set for the user (chmod u+x filename).

Comment: Are you actually using Metacity? If window effects are enabled, then you must configure Compiz instead (use [`ccsm`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/compizconfig-settings-manager)).